# how to call a static method in another static method in the same model laravel

Tags: php, laravel, oop, laravel-5

I created a static method to help me know what mobile OS app my users upload.

```
public static function knowAppPlatform($file){
    $extension=  $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    if ($extension=== "apk"){

        return 'android';
    }
    elseif ($extension=== "appx"){

        return 'windows';
    }
    elseif ($extension=== "ipa"){

        return 'ios';
    }
}
```

Then i tried to call that same static method in another method in the same model. but it keeps returning a null, it works fine outside the model but not inside.

```
 public static function uploadScreenshot($file){
    $platform = static::knowAppPlatform($file);
     dd($platform);
    $name = Auth::id() . 'screenshots' . time(). '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $name = $file->storeAs('mobileApps/screenshots', $name);
    return $name;
}
```

I have researched here on stack overflow and implemented some of the answers, yet no show.

I have tried,

```
$platform = static::knowAppPlatform($file);
$platform = self::knowAppPlatform($file);
$platform = \App\model\students\App::knowAppPlatform($file);
```

Comment: `knowAppPlatform` can return `null` when `$extension` isn't any of `apk`, `appx`, or `ipa`. Are you sure it's one of those in this case? It might help to use a debugger and step through line by line, or (more low-tech) to print out what `$file` and `$extension` are.

Comment: You can call directly by using model name:  ModelName::functionName();

Comment: it's an APK file so it should return true, i tested it outside the model and it worked fine... @tremby

Comment: @RaghbendraNayakSystematix tried that already, but no show

Comment: @Akunne, why would anything return true? Have it `var_dump` out what `$file` and `$extension` are, and let us know.

Comment: @tremby It returned the value as it  was meant to  (apk)... not true

Comment: @Akunne, well that's not the value it's meant to return either, so forgive me if I don't quite trust your responses.

Comment: Where is an emoji when you need one, thanks apparently you were right in your first reply, I dumped the extension variable and found out it was a 'png'. Meaning I was passing the wrong parameter...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently i was passing the wrong file type as a parameter, I passed in a 'png' image type as opposed to a mobile app.

I used used `modelName::methodName` and it worked, The above works as well...

```
self::knowAppPlatform($file);
static::knowAppPlatform($file);
App::knowAppPlatform($file);
```

Comment: Thank you M'Baku, this is working on PHP 8, on Laravel 8.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to call static methods is by using the self keyword   `self::knowAppPlatform($file);` but you said it returns null. I suggest you  try a debugger to solve this issue.